# Converting Time with timezone PHP

Tags: php, datetime-format

I'd like to convert value/date/time that I got from callback
raw value that I got is like this

```
$value='2021-01-20T19:03:52.355+0300';
```

I need to convert it into like this

```
$value='20-01-2021 23.03.52,355000 +07:00';
```

what I've done some substr and concat
but unfortunately it ends up with string and my db datatype format is timestamp and i can't insert the value to db

read some about `DateTime::createFromFormat`
and I can convert the time format but still no clue for converting to another timezone

Comment: The DateTime class would allow you to do timezone changes as well. So yes, if your callback receives the data as string then you'll need to use `createFromFormat` or one of its sister functions.

Comment: could you please help for some example of the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this code, this will work for you and you can set the timezone as per your need.**

```
// Input  : '2021-01-20T19:03:52.355+0300';
// Output : '20-01-2021 23.03.52,355000 +07:00';

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$datetime = new DateTime('2021-01-20T19:03:52.355+0300');

// timezone to convert.
$la_time = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Krasnoyarsk');
$datetime->setTimezone($la_time);
echo $datetime->format('d-m-Y H.i.s,u P');
```

**Output:**

```
20-01-2021 23.03.52,355000 +07:00
```

Answer (score 3):

You could change the timezone using [`setTimezone()`](https://php.net/datetime.settimezone) :

```
$value    = '2021-01-20T19:03:52.355+0300';
$expected = '20-01-2021 23.03.52,355000 +07:00';

$datetime = new \DateTime($value);        
$datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('+0700'));

var_dump($datetime->format('d-m-Y H.i.s,u P') == $expected); // bool(true)
```

Comment: Indeed, great job Syscall that seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$datetime = new \DateTime('2021-01-20T19:03:52.355+0300');
$datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('+0700'));        
date_format($datetime, 'd-m-Y H.i.s,u P');
```

Comment: Time doesn't convert from `+0300` to `+07:00`

Comment: thanks but as @Periklis Kakarakidis said it doesn't convert the time

Comment: @Reza is `+07:00` a standar value? or do you need different time values in other cases?

Comment: my time zone is +07:00 so i guess that would be standard value

Comment: add
**$datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('+0700'));**